# what will happen to images in the Resources directory once the app is packed and how safe are those images for the app?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows

the Resources folder typically contains all the app images (those 16 X16) that we use to look our apps good. I haven't dealt with installation and resources folder before therefore :

1. When application needs to be deployed, what would happen to those images in that Resource folder?
2. I haven't tried this before so when I install the application where would that resource folder be saved?
3. If the installation creates another resource folder to keep those images, then what if a user manually deletes that folder? App would crash? what is the solution to overcome this?
4. I've heard some place the images in a .dll file, is this a common practice?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build your application, Visual Studio invokes the resgen.exe tool to convert your **application resources into an internal class** called Resources. This class is contained in the Resources.Designer.cs file which is nested under the Resources.resx file in Solution Explorer. The Resources class encapsulates all your project resources into static readonly get properties as a way of providing strongly-typed resources at run-time. When you build through the Visual C# IDE, all the encapsulated resource data, including both the resources that were embedded into the .resx file and the linked files, is compiled directly into the **application assembly (the .exe or .dll file)**. In other words, the Visual C# IDE always uses the /resource compiler option. If you build from the command line, you can specify the /linkresource compiler option that will enable you to deploy resources in a separate file from the main application assembly. This is an advanced scenario and is only necessary in certain rare situations. A more common scenario for deploying resources separately from the main application assembly is to use satellite assemblies as discussed below.

All your queries is answered above
i.e. 
When application needs to be deployed, what would happen to those images in that Resource folder? 
I haven't tried this before so when I install the application where would that resource folder be saved?
If the installation creates another resource folder to keep those images, then what if a user manually deletes that folder? App would crash? what is the solution to overcome this?
I've heard some place the images in a .dll file, is this a common practice?

For More information
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.80).aspx